# Creating a point corresponding to the maximum elevation of a DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, point, elevation

I am wondering how can I create a point corresponding to the maximum elevation value of a DEM. I mean, from the DEM I can easily get the maximum elevation. For the sake of a viewshed analysis, I would like to create a point feature corresponding to the spot with maximum elevation. I guess it is simple, but I am having difficulties in finding the right procedure.

I am using arcgis 10.1 (with advanced license).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you compute the statistics of your raster, (or with zonal statistics if you look for a specific zone), you can find its maximum value (properties > source > Statistics > max)

Then you can use the value in raster calculator

```
Con("raster" == maxvalue, 1)
```

EDIt: where *maxvalue* is either the raster created by zonal statistics or the value that you read in the properties.

EDIT Actually it does work in Map algebra. Thank you @WhiteboxDev for the idea :

```
 Con("raster" == "raster".maximum, 1 )
```

and convert the resulting raster to point.

Comment: +1 for use of 'maxvalue' in conditional statement. Very cool.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev sorry, maxvalue is no specal feature, just the name of a variable. I do not deserve your +1 because I was simply unclear.

Comment: It's still a nice approach to the problem!