# What special values can be included in the Con tool's conditional statement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, conditional

I recently read an answer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116824/creating-a-point-corresponding-to-the-maximum-elevation-of-a-dem) question, which used a rather creative solution involving ArcGIS's Raster Calculator. The part that I was most interested in was that the solution's conditional statement,

> Con("raster" == maxvalue, 1)

used the special variable *maxvalue*, clearly the input image's maximum value. I'm curious whether the *maxvalue* variable name can also be used within the conditional statement of the **Con** tool? The documentation for the tool hasn't revealed anything, which makes me think that perhaps it is restricted to the Raster Calculator.

If it is a valid conditional statement for use in the **Con** tool, then what other similar variables are possible? I assume there is a corresponding *minvalue*, but is there a variable for grid cell resolution? How about one for the northern coordinate of the edge of the raster or the y-coordinate for the grid cell?

Comment: Yeah I found the original answer to that post fascinating as well. Had no idea.

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine It's like radouxju is an ArcGIS ninja, isn't it ;)

Comment: Yeah I stared at that answer for about 10 minutes like a deer in headlights. So simple and yet so elegant.

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine Yes, it's so incredibly elegant I did the same thing where I was just staring at it for several minutes. About three days ago I added a tool to Whitebox called 'Find Lowest/Highest Locations' which will create a shapefile of point(s) containing the lowest/highest grid cells of a raster...that's about as simple as it can get. But when I was looking at radouxju's answer, I thought to myself, 'why did I just spend all that time writing that tool and why didn't I think of that?' Ha!

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you but I am no ninja. I just meant that the maximum value from the first step , so that the OP had to fill with his maximum value (a raster layer if he used zonal stat, or a numeric value. I've tried just in case but maxvalue does not work.

Comment: @radouxju Ah, that is disappointing, I thought that you had some hidden secret functionality like an Easter egg. But it's an answer nonetheless. Would you mind posting your answer so that I can accept it? Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: the question was so good that there was an answer !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the arcpy syntax can be used directly in raster calculator. Therefore the properties of [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000) can be used. For instance

```
Con("raster" > "raster".mean, 1, 0)
```

works. Other examples :

minimum, maximum, mean, meanCellHeight, meanCellWidth, extent.XMin, extent.YMax, etc

Comment: Now that is truly very cool! I think I would rate this is one of my favourite all-time answers. Thanks.